# str_replace is not working properly

Tags: php, google-maps, str-replace, google-maps-static-api

Hi im gonna trying to add x,y location to my static google maps image location string that is

```
$googlemapstatic="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=(location)&zoom=7&size=1000x1000&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|11211&sensor=false&markers=size:mid|color:0x000000|label:1|(location)";
```

and i have x and y for its latitude and longitude

```
$koorX='32.323213123';
$koorY='39.3213';
```

and im using str replace for changing static maps location and marker inside it.

```
$newlocation=$koorX.','.$koorY;
$googlemapstatic=str_replace('location',$newlocation,$googlemapstatic);
```

but it shows me different location than input.

```
<img style='width:15.61cm; height:12.0cm' src=".$googlemapstatic.'>
```

If i write that x,y manually from browser, it show correct location. 
I assume that there is some mistake in str_replace function but i couldn't find it.

Comment: Check what real value you get after replacing. You'd better to store replacing result in another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

if deprecated kind of error then try to use str_ireplace

```
$newlocation=$koorX.','.$koorY;
$googlemapstatic=str_ireplace('location',$newlocation,$googlemapstatic);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one :

```
$googlemapstatic = str_replace('(location)','('.$newlocation.')',$googlemapstatic);
```